# Issue with Delphi DFM inheritance

Tags: delphi

i dont have much time, i will try to get right to the point.

(This is all design-time, refreshing the DFM with alt+F12 2x)

Normally, i get this (What i want):

```
object Form1: TForm1
   object Father: TFather
      object Son: TSon
      end
   end
end
```

When i refresh the dfm, and the Delphi Reader runs... i get that:

```
object Form1: TForm1
   object Father: TFather
   end
   object Son: TSon
   end
end
```

Why the son get out of the father? I am setting Father the Owner of Son at the moment of Son's creation.

I need to do something else? I also tried to override GetOwner of Son, but with no success.

Any ideas?

Comment: what if you manually copy the dfm source to what you want. Does it correctly retain the parent relationship then?

Comment: What do you mean by don't having much time?

Comment: By trying to get right to the point, and by not taking enough time to explain your problem, you have asked a question that cannot be definitively answered. This is known as making a false economy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information stored in the dfm is only what you design. The nesting is about parent/child relations, not about ownership. This dfm suggests that Son is no longer the Parent of Father. This may be caused by code in TSon that modifies it's own parent.

Comment: This is it! The concept of parenting was the issue. Thank you very much.